# Error: Unable to find an active device after upgrade to Appium 1.5.3

Tags: appium, genymotion

I upgraded to Appium1.5 and now when I launch and try to run my tests I am seeing this error :
Checking my settings and all seems fine and even the inspector works fine .

[AndroidDriver] Error: Unable to find an active device or emulator with OS 1. The following are available: 192.168.99.101:5555 (4.3)
    at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (lib/logger.js:60:13)
    at Object.callee$0$0$ (lib/android-helpers.js:154:16)
    at tryCatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
    at run (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/es6.promise.js:104:47)
    at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/es6.promise.js:115:28
    at flush (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/$.microtask.js:19:5)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
 [Error: Unable to find an active device or emulator with OS 1. The following are available: 192.168.99.101:5555 (4.3)]

[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Unable to find an active device or emulator with OS 1. The following are available: 192.168.99.101:5555 (4.3)
    at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (lib/logger.js:60:13)
    at Object.callee$0$0$ (lib/android-helpers.js:154:16)
    at tryCatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
    at run (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/es6.promise.js:104:47)
    at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/es6.promise.js:115:28
    at flush (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/$.microtask.js:19:5)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the platform version as capability as following -

```
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "7.1");
```

My version is 7.1, use the version which is right for you

Answer (score 0):

1.If you want to work with appium version 1.5 again then you can do following things.

Uninstall appium and then install appium for specific version

```
   npm uninstall -g appium 

   npm install -g appium@1.5 

   appium -v
```

2.Now suppose in case if you update appium version then you need to update then all maven dependencies,java,testng etc.

Suppose if you install latest appium then you need to check first your previos xcode,android and all dependencies works for it.

3.If upgrading the version not working then it could be problem with appium version so you have to revert back to your old version which was working fine as 1st option.

Answer (score -1):

craj, may be it is the problem of the adb not of appium.
Had you tried adb devices on cmd?